# Unable to create file error, file doesn't exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, operating-system, tensorboard

I'm trying to create an RNN with Tensorflow, but when I try to save the model I get an error:

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'models/RNN_Final-01-0.502.model', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

It says unable to open file, but I don't think I'm trying to open a file. I'm trying to save a file. Below is the section of code returning the error.

```
    # Compile model
    model.compile(
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=opt,
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\{}".format(NAME))
    
    filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}"  # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones
    
    # Train model
    history = model.fit(
        train_x, train_y,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
        callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
    )
    
    # Score model
    score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    # Save model
    model.save("models\{}".format(NAME))
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but what if you try with a file name that does not contain any dot ('.') except for the one that precedes '.model' ?

Answer (score 0):

try to save .h5 and give the full path, where you want to save

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.h5".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max'))
```